# What textbooks should I use for Trigonometry and Calculus? My basics are terrible.

Tags: sequences-and-series, group-theory, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I need help really bad. I have a paper coming up in two months and all topics require at least basic if not intermediate understanding in trigonometry and calculus. I don't know how I got so far - by memorizing formulas just before an exam. I like mathematics but I am terrible at learning these identities.

I have one paper coming up and need a lot of practice. These are the topics that is going to be covered in the paper:

***Differential calculus:***

> Definition of the limit of a function in ε-δ form- Algebra of
>   limits-Continuity of a function - types of discontinuities -properties
>   of continuous functions on a closed interval (boundedness, attainment
>   of bounds and taking every value between bounds) - differentiability,
>   differentiability implies continuity and converse is not true. Rolle’s
>   theorem-Lagrange’s and Cauchy’s first mean value theorems - Taylors’
>   theorem with Lagrange’s form of remainder - Maclaurin’s expansion-
>   problems. Evaluation of limits by L’Hospital’s rule (indeterminate
>   form).

***Group Theory:***

> Recapitulation of the definition and standard properties of groups and
>   subgroups Cyclic groups- properties-order of an element of a group-
>   properties related to order of an elementsubgroup generated by an
>   element of a group- coset decomposition of a group- modulus relation-
>   index of a group- Lagrange's theorem for finite groups-consequences.

***Sequences:***

> Definition of a sequence-limit of a sequence-algebre of limits.
>   Convergent, divergent and oscillatory sequence-infimum-supremum-Nature
>   of the sequences theorems-problems-monotonicity-problems-cauchy
>   sequences.

***Series:***

> Definition of Convergence-divergence-oscillation-properties of
>   convergent series- Cauchy’s theorem-geometric series - p-series
>   -comparison tests, De'alembert's test, Raabe's tests. Cauchy root test - problems. (The following tests are without proof) Absolute-conditional convergence-De'alembert's test for absolute
>   convergence Alternating series. Summation of series - binomial,
>   exponential and logarithmic series.

***Differential Equations:***

> i. Formation and solution of ordinary differential equations (I order
>   & I degree). a) Variable-separable and reducible to variable separable
>   form b) Homogeneous & reducible to homogeneous forms c) Linear
>   equations- Bernoulli’s equations and those reducible to these
>   equations d) Exact equations and reducible to exact with standard
>   integrating factors ii. Equation of first order and higher
>   degree-Clairaut’s equation -general and singular solutions- geometric
>   meaning. iii. Orthogonal trajectories in cartesian and polar forms.

How should I go about learning the basics for these topics in order to understand the syllabus better?

Thank you so much.

Comment: It doesn't look like you even need trigonometry except to solve 2nd order linear differential equations.  All of these topics are much more difficult to understand than trigonometry I think.  How comfortable are you with this extremely long list of material?  My recommendation would depend on this.

Comment: I was trying to solve problems in limits and a lot of questions required knowing integration and differentiation of trigonometry. Many require a knowledge of double angles, how to write something in terms of something else. I am so bad at even explaining the sums I do.

I am fairly comfortable with Differential Equations because it is straightforward.

Sequence and Series is difficult for me as well.

Group Theory is easy when I study it but during the exam, I blank out. Concepts are easy to understand. 

My main problem is with Differential Calculus. With all the formulas involved.

Comment: I am not sure if you're still going to post...? Let me know if I need to clarify something for you.

Comment: @IshanJalan, do you have recommended texts for your course?

Comment: @John No, not really. They have some local textbooks that are pretty terrible. Explain things in really brief, provide some solved examples and get on with exercises and answers at the back of the book.

Comment: @John anything you'd recommend to me? I would prefer a basic book and not too proof-heavy. Clean, easy to understand, logical, examples, applications, etc.

Comment: @IshanJalan, why not try engineering mathematics by KA. Stroud. For topics not covered in this text, you can always try shaum's outlines-https://www.mhprofessional.com/category/?cat=3959.

Answer (score 1):

Many trig formulas are things you just look up (or memorize).  They can also be sometimes be derived from each other.  For example, knowing $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x =1$, dividing by $\cos^2 x$ yields $\tan^2 x + 1 = \sec^2 x.$  A useful exercise would be to take a list of rules (maybe from your textbook) and see which ones can be derived from other ones.  It seems like you shouldn't spend too much time on trig, as long as you know what the 6 trig functions mean and how they're related to each other.

Now for some general comments on preparing for your exam:  Of course you want to work on problems given to you, working your way from getting assistance towards doing the problem without referring to a textbook/the internet.

Something that may help with forgetting things when the exam comes, is to choose a topic and come up with examples to play with. For example in group theory, take your specimens to be the integers mod 3, the integers mod 6, the integers mod 9, and the integers mod 12 (I'm just picking a variety of things).  Now you can verify that these are groups by checking the properties.  What are all of their subgroups?  What are the cosets of those subgroups?  What is everything that Lagrange's theorem tells you about each of the groups?  Compare and contrast the answers of all of these questions for the different groups.

I assume you have a textbook or some sort of resource from the time you learned these things to begin with.  Most textbooks are probably fine as long as they cover the material you listed and have lots of practice problems.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, mathematician. :)

I do have textbooks but they do a terrible job at explaining concepts and get straight into exercises and sums. My problems arise when it comes to integrating and differentiating, say tan squared theta or sin inverse and other such problems. My sums just come to a halt when I hit these walls. Is there a way of memorising them using logic/common sense and so?

Believe it or not, I am doing a Bachelors in Mathematics and I am terrible at these basic things. Almost every semester has topics that require Calculus and I barely manage to scrape through.

Comment: Lots of trig integration problems have a "trick" to them.  Like to integrate $\sin^2 x$ you want to rewrite it as $\frac{1}{2} (1-\cos(2x))$ (an identity that I never remember) then use substitution.  But there are only so many kinds of these tricky problems.  Once you see them all you just have to remember the different tricks (using an identity, or a not obvious substitution).  So do lots of practice problems, getting help from the internet/people/wherever, until all of the problems you find are just different versions of what you've already done.

Answer (score 1):

for basics of trigonometry you can go for S.L. lony bok,
and the topics what you have mentioned i will suggest two books 
1) advanced engineering mathematics by erwin kreyszig
2) advanced engineering mathematics by ramana
the first one is for deep understanding of the topics and second one is for practice. 
also if you are still looking for further basics in this topics you can try any demystify maths 
all the best and enjoy reading 
regards 
chirag

Comment: Suggest ramana book.that is not a good but i hear ftom my friend who is an indian, thatIndian university follows it... It 's unfortunate and stupid